# Ember Data models not becoming dirty when relationships are modified

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've got a model in my Ember application that has a hasMany relationship:

```
App.Book = DS.Model.extend({
  tags: DS.hasMany('tag')
});
```

The problem is that when adding/removing a tag to/from a book, the book model itself does not become "dirty". For example:

```
book = this.store.find('book', 123);
book.get('tags.length')
==> 0
tag = this.store.find('tag', 456);
book.get('tags').pushObject(tag);
book.get('tags.length')
==> 1
book.get('isDirty') // should be true, but is false
==> false
```

It seems to me that `book` instance should now be dirty since one of its relationships was changed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like a bug, can you set up a jsbin showing the problem?

Comment: By the way, it looks like you are pushing a promise into your tags array, is that intentional?  (Ember Data returns a promise from the find call)

Comment: I actually just didn't want to deal with promises to make this code a little easier to read. In my actual application I do it the right way. Also, I'll try to create a jsbin now.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this? I'm seeing there have been issues with dirty records in the past couple months in Ember Data, but I'm trying to figure if this is intentional or if it's actually a bug in Ember-Data.

Comment: Never found a solution. I posted about it on Ember's Discourse forums, but nobody replied. For now, I'm just manually calling `record.send('becomeDirty')` when I modify a record's relationships.

Comment: I read that you can solve this by setting an explicit inverse (see http://emberjs.com/guides/models/defining-models/) on the other model -- Tag in this case, but there may be other factors too.

Comment: Latest ember data does not dirty the record for a hasMany relationship. See this issue: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1367.

Comment: @NudeCanalTroll Can you answer your own question for now? Given that Ember Data is only still in beta, and this is a known issue (there are several tracking issues for it in the ember repo) and the SSOT branch will indubitably address these issues, it'd be good if you could close it.

Comment: "Never found a solution. " ... "For now, I'm just manually calling record.send('becomeDirty')" - yup, that's exactly what I ended up doing. See the [issue I raised](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/2010). @JulianLeviston when you say SSOT branch, are you referring [to this one](https://github.com/emberjs/data/tree/wip-ssot-es6)?

Comment: @bguiz that could be part of it, but mostly this one as far as I know (which isn't very far): https://github.com/emberjs/data/tree/single-source-of-truth

Comment: BTW, I ended up doing what you did, too. I hope we see 1.0 release or SSOT merge soon. It's kinda sucking meantime.

Comment: @JulianLeviston both of those branches look like they have been on their own for a **long** time (one since april and the other since march). Yes, it really does suck in the mean time.

Comment: @bguiz most of the work happens on particular key committers' repos. Github kinda sucks for the 'what activity has been taking place' use-case, IMHO.

Comment: Any news for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temporary solution is to manually call `record.send('becomeDirty')` after modifying the record's relationships.